# Sharepoint Calculated column - not working

Tags: list, formula

The column titled "has submission gone" has a formula, see below:

=IF([Date of Submission]<=TODAY(),"Yes","No")

The column Submission Gone will have yes or no, so if the date is less than todays date, it will place a Yes in the column, if more than todays date, it will put No.
The formula worked for dates up to the end of 2022, but does not work for dates in 2023 (see below screenshot)

[image]

Any suggestions?

Wayne

Comment: I tried it out on my side and it worked as expected. Is your "Date of Submission" a 'Date and Time' column type?

Comment: @thebernardlim Yes the column is Date and Time, I don't have any other option to change it too. It has friendly format selected too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the issue is related to the date format in your SharePoint list. By default, SharePoint uses the `MM/DD/YYYY` format for dates, which may be causing issues with the formula for dates in 2023.

To ensure that the formula works correctly for all dates, you can try modifying the formula to use the DATE function to specify the date format:

```
=IF([Date of Submission]<=TODAY(),"Yes","No")
```

can be updated to:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR([Date of Submission]),MONTH([Date of Submission]),DAY([Date of Submission]))<=TODAY(),"Yes","No")
```

This updated formula should ensure that the formula works correctly for all dates, regardless of the date format used in your SharePoint list.

Comment: Thank you @pradip

Comment: Hi, sorry, this formula did work initially, but has decided to stop working again. I am unsure if Microsoft Sharepoint is the problem or my organisation sharepoint settings, etc is the issue.

Comment: Please verify whether your column formatting has been modified to a different setting. Additionally, ensure that the `Date of Submission` field type remains as "Date and Time." I recommend thoroughly examining each section of the code I provided in your column to retrieve the values and combine them accurately.

Comment: Hello, I have checked the settings, the submisson column is date and time